# Why is my scope variable losing its value from angular.copy?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, copy

Every example looks like this should be working, so I'll make this quick.

// Click on a table row

ng-click="setBill(bill)"

```
$scope.setBill = function (bill) {
    $scope.selectedBill = angular.copy(bill);  // shouldn't this set a deep copy?
    alert($scope.selectedBill.meterNumber);  // Outputs properly
}
```

// Click on a button

ng-click="btnInsertData()"

```
$scope.btnInsertData = function () {
    alert($scope.selectedBill.meterNumber);    // $scope.selectedBill is undefined
    return;
}
```

// Requested calls from html above

```
<tr ng-repeat="bill in billItems" ng-click="setBill(bill)" ng-class="{'selected':bill.meterNumber == selectedBill.meterNumber}">
    ...
    <td>{{bill.meterNumber}}</td>
    ...
</tr>
...
<button ng-click="btnInsertData()">Submit to VP</button>
```

Comment: We would have to see the HTML where the `ng-click="setBill(bill)"` is, but if `$scope.selectedBill` is undefined it must mean that `bill` is undefined when you pass it to `$scope.setBill`. If you add a `console.log(bill);` line right above where you are assiging to your scope variable what does it show?

Comment: Provide an [mcve]. There is nothing shown that would give us any indication of when either of these 2 methods get called

Comment: @Lex I disagree. bill is definitely defined - per my note that the first alert() outputs actual data. It's as if the $scope.selectedBill object loses its scope after exiting setBill()... which doesn't make sense to me. I'll add the tr ng-repeat above as requested.

Comment: Ah...my bad. Totally missed that comment. Something is occurring between `setBill` and `btnInsertData` to either `$scope` in general or `$scope.selectedBill` specifically.

Comment: @Lex Winner! Wow. Such a dumb mistake. I had two separate "ng-controller" declarations (not sure why, I was testing to see if it would break; which yes and no). Thanks for the kick.